# How to convert Geom_bSplineSurface to a TopoDS_Shape or face after some local modification in the Geom_bSplineSurface?

Tags: opencascade

I'm Rennngw.
I read a step model, then converted one of the TopoDS_Face to Geom_BSplineSurface, and then reparametrized the Geom_BSplineSurface, now I want to re-convert the reparametrized Geom_BSplineSurface to TopoDS_Face, but I found that there is a problem with the result of my conversion: a circle surface becomes a square. How can I do it to get the result I want？

Below is my code and conversion result.

```
 TopoDS_Face faceo = TopoDS::Face(face_shape);
    BRepBuilderAPI_NurbsConvert nurbs_convert;
    nurbs_convert = BRepBuilderAPI_NurbsConvert(faceo);
    nurbs_convert.Perform(faceo);
    TopoDS_Shape face_shape = nurbs_convert.Shape();
    Handle(Geom_Surface) h_geomface = BRep_Tool::Surface(TopoDS::Face(face_shape));
    Handle(Geom_BSplineSurface)h_bsurface = GeomConvert::SurfaceToBSplineSurface(h_geomface);
    
    //Reparametrize u dir
    Standard_Integer nbuk = h_bsurface->NbUKnots();
    TColStd_Array1OfReal uk(1, nbuk);
    BSplCLib::Reparametrize(0, 1, uk);
    h_bsurface->SetUKnots(uk);
    
    //Reparametrize v dir
    Standard_Integer nbvk = h_bsurface->NbVKnots();
    TColStd_Array1OfReal vk(1, nbvk);
    BSplCLib::Reparametrize(0, 1, vk);
    h_bsurface->SetVKnots(vk);
    
    //convert Geom_BSplineSurface to TopoDS_Face
    TopoDS_Face res = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace(h_bsurface, Precision::Approximation());
```

The left image is the original graph, which is the result I want to get.

The right image is the wrong result of my code running.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1aDh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmjMu.png)

How can I convert Geom_bSplineSurface to a TopoDS_Shape or face after some local modification in the Geom_bSplineSurface?

Thank you very much!

I read a step model, then converted one of the TopoDS_Face to Geom_BSplineSurface, and then reparametrized the Geom_BSplineSurface, now I want to re-convert the reparametrized Geom_BSplineSurface to TopoDS_Face, but I found that there is a problem with the result of my conversion: a circle surface becomes a square.

Comment: The basic issue is that you are creating new Face without any bounds - you have to reuse Wires and Edges of original Face and create new ones adopted to new surface. This means that you'll have to manually re-create 2D curves on Edges within new UV surface range or use some tool re-projecting 3D curve onto new surface to create P-curves, and then make new Face with these new Wires + new surface.